# How can i include a js file in another js file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i have a `bot.js` file and `set.js` file with the following code

```
const stage = new Stage([greeterScene,adminscene], { ttl: 1800 })
bot.use(session())
bot.use(stage.middleware())
```

the code in `set.js` files requires modules imported in `bot.js` file which is

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const Extra = require('telegraf/extra');
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup');
const bot = new Telegraf("token");
const Scene = require('telegraf/scenes/base')
const session = require('telegraf/session')
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage')
```

so how can i include my `set.js` file in the main `bot.js` file??

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried requiring `set.js` in `bot.js`? If yes, is that giving you an error or some unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require JS files.

E.g. Adding the following line in bot.js `require("./set.js")` or `let setFunctions = require("./set.js")`, ideally near the top, before you call any of the functions from that file.